# Sort the string paths in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am scanning a directory through my program to pickup a number of the images and their paths. Inside the directory, the images are arranged in the following manner:

`1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png etc.`

When the directory is scanned:

```
for(int i=0;i<dir.numFiles();++i){
string path = dir.getPath(i);
imageSeq.push_back(CustomImage.loadImage(path));
}
private:
vector<CustomImages> imageSeq;
```

The problem with the above code is that the images come out to be randomly picked up from the directory. I wanted the images to be sorted according to their names and pushed into vectors. I have some constraints here:

1) CustomImage has not exposed an `imageName` type of method, with which I could have used to compare with the last vector while I push new `paths` into the imageSeq vector
2) I can't modify the vector imageSeq to take in strings and then loop in again to load the images afterwards. Doing that will increase the space taken.

How do I sort those images in the vector so that they are arranged according to their names?

Comment: What is `dir` and how is it used?

Comment: Then sort `dir` first before iterating it.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the names lexicographically, use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
std::sort(imageSeq.begin(), imageSeq.end());
```

However, lexicographical order will mean that `15.png` will come *before* `2.png`. To remedy this, you need to implement a [natural sort comparator](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) which isn’t trivial unless you know the exact format the file names come in, then you can parse them accordingly.

Comment: As I understood, you cannot sort `imageSeq`, because it contains images, not paths.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can firstly read all paths, sort them and then iterate over sorted vector, just like this :

```
#include<algorithm>
...
vector<string> help_vector;
for(int i=0;i<dir.numFiles();++i){
    string path = dir.getPath(i);
    help_vector.push_back(path);
}
sort(help_vector.begin(),help_vector.end());

for(int i=0;i<help_vector.size();i++)
    imageSeq.push_back(CustomImage.loadImage(help_vector[i]));
```